# Radical of an infinite dimensional Lie Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-algebras

I am studying Lie Algebras and I just encountered the notion of *radical* $R$ of a finite dimensional Lie algebra $L$ over a field $F$, the maximal solvable ideal. Since the dimension of $L$ is finite, every increasing chain of solvable ideals is bounded, then exists a maximal element, and since the sums of two maximal solvable ideals still remains solvable, the maximal solvable ideal above is unique (and then well defined).
Can we find some similar notions in the case $\dim_F (L)= \infty$?
In the construction above we have used that every chain of solvable ideals has an upper bound, that may be not true in the infinite dimensional case.

For example, there is a way to build a Lie algebra with a series of ideals $0=I_0<I_1<I_2<\ldots$ in which $(I_{i+1})'= I_i$ (here $L'$ is the derivated algebra of $L$)?
If yes, this would means that the notion above of radical can't be extended, because $I=\bigcup_{j \ge 0}Ij$ would be not solvable.

Comment: Are you sure that the summation in the finite dimensional case is finite? (Not that it matters...)

Comment: No absolutely: the number of lines of the plane is not countable.
I edit right now.

Comment: Thank you, your note helped me to make a better question.

Comment: This has been explained by Shigeaki Togo in his paper [Radicals of Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206137812) of $1972$. Togo defines local solvability and then can define several solvable radicals for infinite-dimensional Lie algebras.